# ^L while tail -f is running

Tags: linux, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, tail

I frequently use `tail` to monitor errors:

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log
```

I can use the shortcut `cmd+K` to clear the screen (OSX), but I've grown accustomed to using `^L` in other linuxy situations. When I attempt to use it while `tail` is monitoring a file, I see output `^L` instead:

```
[Fri Sep 30 12:08:58 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.19 (Unix) PHP/5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.1 configured -- resuming normal operations
^L^L^L^L
```

Is there a way to get `^L` to work the way i'm expecting it to in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Application Shortcuts* and assign `^L` as keyboard shortcut for the *Clear Scrollback* menu item in `Terminal.app`.

[image]

---

`^L` (Form Feed) is different from *Clear Scrollback* though if you have Terminal's scroll back enabled — the former keeps all output and just scrolls down, printing a new prompt.

Comment: Ah I see. this works, though it changes the behavior of `^L` in other situations. Is it not possible to form feed when tail is monitoring a file (since the prompt is not available, maybe)?